Is there any code benefit to removing disconnected underground wire
My home has some underground wiring that has existed since before I purchased the home. I’ve verified that the wires are completely disconnected from any live circuit and located both ends. The interior end terminates in my garage and the exterior end pops up in my lawn. May have been intended for an exterior lamp, but found street view images that show it’s been in this state for at least a decade.
Can I cut the wire where it exits the house, remove the portion in the house, and just bury the exterior without worrying about code issues? The wire runs beneath a concrete walkway and I cannot seem to pull it through its plastic conduit.

Wires that are not connected to anything at either end are trash. If in your home or yard, you can remove them without repercussion.  I know of no code that governs disconnected abandoned wires.

If you ever excavate, code requires separation of metals and some other materials from clean fill taken off the site, and suitable disposal. The garbage wire has to go to the right place.  Not a concern now.

IIRC code requires the removal of all accessible parts of "abandoned wires/cables" (as distinct from "not in use but might be used later wires/cables" which have to be tagged. Rarely enforced, though.
